# Showing a Visual Studio 2005 window at design time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Working on Visual Studio 97 pressing Ctrl+D the window that was designed was popped-up. What are the equivalent keys in VS 2005?

Comment: F7 = view code, Shift+F7 = view designer.  These shortcut keys are readily visible in the View menu.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `F7` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Sunscreen F7 will toggle between code and designer.  If you are in designer, F7 will bring you to code.  If you are in code, F7 will bring you to the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines are your friend :)
Try [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366739%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

As Shark says (+1 btw) it reckons `shift+F7` is the default for designer view, but this only shows the selected item in designer view and if it doesn't "compile" then you wont be able to view it.